# Embedded orbeon: blank test page

Tags: orbeon

I have an (java/jsp) embedded form builder (version 2019.2.0.201912301747) and I would like to use the test button, but I get an empty iframe on the popup window and indeed, the embedded fb-test-iframe iframe's src is an about:blank.
Although the same is true when I drop the orbeon.war to an empty tomcat and run the form builder there, there the test page works correctly (I have to add that I have implemented a custom persistence API for my orbeon instance, maybe I should have specified somewhere some related url, I have specified only the **oxf.fr.persistence.${my persistence id}.uri** .)

Unfortunately there is no network activity in the browser debug (maybe because of the iframe) and no browser error, it just does not work :(

Unfortunately the documentation does not really explain the way of working of the test button.

What and where should I configure in Orbeon to force it to, I don't know, raise an event that triggers something in orbeon to load something (ideally a form runner instance that loads the currently edited form) to there?

Update #1:
After switching to orbeon-2018.2.4.201911212304-PE.zip (but keeping the 2019 libs where it is embedded), I was able to get it to communicate, so I am a bit further. Now as it is visible on the picture, the embedded orbeon sends data to its backend, and the request arrived the orbeon backend according to its logs.
[orbeon.war log](https://pastebin.pl/view/56bb4760)
But **there is no answer to the last request**, this is the key I think, but I don't understand why. As if there would be a further call (maybe towards the orbeon CRUD API backend, and there would be no connect/read timeout for that connection).

But there is no further communication towards the crud api, there is no new entries in the crud api backend log.

[image: orbeon test button communication]

My [properties-local-prod.xml](https://pastebin.pl/view/d868cff6)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see if we can figure this out. Are you using the [Java embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api)? Also, what version of Orbeon Forms are you using? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi, Yes, I am using that embedding API. The latest CE edition which I use. form-builder and form-runner: 2019.2.0.201912301747 (extracted from their jar's manifest)

Comment: Got it; I don't think that your custom implementation of the persistence API should come into the picture, but just in case: are you able to reproduce this with a verbatim install of Orbeon Forms, that is with no custom properties? ‑Alex

Comment: I will try to do that in the afternoon.

Comment: Have you found what was going on with the Test button? If not yet, did you get a chance to try if you're also having the problem with a verbatim install of Orbeon Forms? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi, I made a test app and embedded the OOTB orbeon to there. There is no test button there, instead of that there is a review button, probably with the same functionality. Unfortunately that thing works well :(

Comment: I was wrong, I have tested the runner first. I added a jsp with the embedded formbuilder too, the test button is visible there. Unfortunately (from my point of view), with the standard orbeon.war it works well :( so I did something wrong in my custom orbeon.war or in my custom persistence layer.

Comment: If someone would like to do some similar check, I put my test application to this [repo](https://github.com/jmalyik/orbeon-embedding)

Comment: Got it, so hopefully you can find what is different in your app that triggers that empty page on Test. You'll let me know what your findings are, and if there is something we can help with along the way. ‑Alex

Answer (score 0):

OP mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045526/embedded-orbeon-blank-test-page#comment113472166_64045526) that this doesn't happen with an out-of-the-box install of Orbeon Forms, and thus suspects the issue they are having was due to some change they inadvertently made to Orbeon Forms.